# Tensorflow is failing at idiomatically simple piece of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) to play with Tensorflow. I'm trying to evaluate simple perceptron created by hand rather than using Keras with eager execution mode.

The perceptron is expecting input of (1x2) tensor, there are two layers consisting of following weights and biases `W1:(2x2)` / `B1:(1x2)` and `W2:(2x1)` / `B2:(1x1)`,

And I have found this simple piece of code failing at my face for no apparent reason. The seems somehow related to optimizers, every optimizer I've tried failed with different errors. For example for optimizer used below (GradientDescentOptimizer) Tensorflow says that the operation is not implemented, I can't figure out why. Here is self-sufficient piece of code (Tensorflow 1.13.1 / Python3):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tf.enable_eager_execution()
with tf.device("GPU:0"):
  W1 = tf.random_uniform([2, 2], -1, 1, tf.float32)
  B1 = tf.random_uniform([1, 2], -1, 1, tf.float32)

  W2 = tf.random_uniform([2, 1], -1, 1, tf.float32)
  B2 = tf.random_uniform([1, 1], -1, 1, tf.float32)

  X0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[0, 0]]), tf.float32)

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(W1)
    tape.watch(B1)
    tape.watch(W2)
    tape.watch(B2)

    X1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X0, W1) + B1)
    X2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X1, W2) + B2)

    Loss = tf.square(X2 - tf.constant([[1]], tf.float32))

  dLoss_dParams = tape.gradient(Loss, [W1, B1, W2, B2])  

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dLoss_dParams, [W1, B1, W2, B2]), tf.Variable(0))
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `W1`, `B1`, `W2` and `B2` are regular tensors, which cannot be changed. Optimizers can only work with `tf.Variable` objects, which are like tensors but they can be updated. You can initialize a variable with a random value, but not use the result of the random operation itself as a variable directly.

Comment: Thank you @jdehesa! Using `tf.Variable` did help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just in case someone else would bump into the same problem. As per @jdehesa's answer in the comments the resulting code would look like the following (I've updated original code, now the perceptron is trying to solve xor problem):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

tf.enable_eager_execution()

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()

with tf.device("GPU:0"):
  X0 = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], np.float32) # 4x2

  W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 2], -1.0, 1.0, tf.float32)) # 4x2 * 2x2 => 4x2
  B1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1, 2], -1.0, 1.0, tf.float32)) # 4x2 + 1x2 => 4x2

  W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 1], -1.0, 1.0, tf.float32)) # 4x2 * 2x1 => 4x1
  B2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1, 1], -1.0, 1.0, tf.float32)) # 4x1 + 1x1 => 4x1

  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    #     tape.watch(W1)
    #     tape.watch(B1)
    #     tape.watch(W2)
    #     tape.watch(B2)

    X1 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(X0, W1) + B1)
    X2 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(X1, W2) + B2)

    Loss = tf.square(X2 - tf.constant([[0], [1], [1], [0]], tf.float32))

  dLoss_dParams = tape.gradient(Loss, [W1, B1, W2, B2])
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dLoss_dParams, [W1, B1, W2, B2]))
  print(Loss.numpy()[0][0]) 

for i in range(10000):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    X1 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(X0, W1) + B1)
    X2 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(X1, W2) + B2)

    Loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(X2 - tf.constant([[0], [1], [1], [0]], tf.float32)))

  dLoss_dParams = tape.gradient(Loss, [W1, B1, W2, B2])  
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dLoss_dParams, [W1, B1, W2, B2]))

  if i % 1000 == 0:
    print(Loss.numpy())

X1 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(X0, W1) + B1)
X2 = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(X1, W2) + B2)

print(X2.numpy()[0][0])
print(X2.numpy()[1][0])
print(X2.numpy()[2][0])
print(X2.numpy()[3][0])
```